# What different between Scroll and PageCurl in modalTransitionStyle in PageViewController

Tags: xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have a problem in My app that if I swipe the screen right for example in my pageViewController the method that call oncs is

In PageCurl mood.

```
-viewControllerAfterViewController
```

and when I swipe to left the method that call is :

```
-viewControllerBeforeViewController
```

In Scroll mood I have the problem.

when I swipe to left the methods call together :

```
-viewControllerAfterViewController 

-viewControllerBeforeViewController
```

I need when I swipe to right only the -viewControllerAfterViewController call

and when I swipe to left only the -viewControllerBeforeViewController call

what the problem in Scroll mood ?

```
 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController       *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(PhotoViewController *)viewController
{
if ((int)viewController.pageIndex == [imagesNames count] - 1)
{
    return nil;
}
else
{
    currentVisibleImageNumber++;
    [self updatePicturesCounterLabel];
    return [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithIndex:viewController.pageIndex + 1 atDictionary:CurrentUser.profileImages withKey:@"profile" bottomHeight:myDescriptionViewHeight];
}
```

}

```
     -(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController  *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(PhotoViewController *)viewController
{
if (viewController.pageIndex == 0)
{
    return nil;
}
else
{
    currentVisibleImageNumber--;
    [self updatePicturesCounterLabel];
    return [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithIndex:viewController.pageIndex - 1 atDictionary:CurrentUser.profileImages withKey:@"profile" bottomHeight:myDescriptionViewHeight];
}
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug in iOS, its something that is needed to make the PageViewController with scroll transition work.

When the transition style is scroll, a scroll view is inserted into the view hierarchy and both methods are called to get the previous and the next view controllers, so in case the user scrolled partially, he/she should be able to see next(or previous) and current view controller at the same time.

Whereas on the PageCurl transition style, there is no such case.

Comment: Ok , now if I want the index in the current page ? you can see in the code I upload that I have a currentVisibleImageNumber that show the user which page he stop.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can use the viewController.pageIndex to store the current view controller's page index. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: No , and I try t work with viewController.pageIndex.

Comment: Can you explain the problem? 

A good practice to keep count of the current index is to have a model(e.g an array) of your view controllers' id's that you are loading on your PageViewController(when calling the setViewControllers method) and than on viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController you would be able to ask your model about the index of the current view controller's id something like this:
[self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController.pageID].

Comment: There is some way to bring from this function the current page I am in ?                                - (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed

Comment: "Current number page" is the index of the current view controller's id that I explained on my previous comment.